# how to combine lines relative to first column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to reformat a csv file combine several field lines together, but relative to the first field
So looking at the picture attached [image: edited screenshot] the top screenshot is a sample of what I have ( 1000s of lines), but i need it to be formatted so that the "media image" text are are all on one line for each sku (from the first column),  as shown in the bottom screenshot.  is there a why to do this?

Note file names for the jpg are not always sequential, like they are in the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+

- Select a cell in the table

  - Data / Get&Transform / From Table/Range
- You can do this all from the Power Query UI

**Algorithm**

- Select the `sku` column and "fill down"
- `Group By` SKU with Operation of `All Rows`

  - extract the `_media_attribute_id`

    - Since these are all the same, we just extract the first one.
  - Extract a `List` of the elements of the _image_media column
  - From that list extract the elements as a comma separated text string

If you paste the M-Code into the Advanced Editor, you can change the `Table` name in Line 2 to the real table name of your data in your worksheet.

You can then examine the steps in the `Applied Steps` panel to understand what is happening.

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"sku", type text}, {"_media_attribute_id", Int64.Type}, {"_media_image", type text}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"sku"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"sku"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [sku=nullable text, _media_attribute_id=nullable number, _media_image=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "_media_attribute_id", each List.First(Table.Column([Grouped],"_media_attribute_id"))),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "_media_image", each Table.Column([Grouped],"_media_image")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"_media_image", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Again i'm sure i'm doing something stupid, but when I "fill down" nothing happens https://snipboard.io/GU14nF.jpg

Comment: @paddyD You have a space or nonprinting character in those cells. Need to figure out what it is and add code to remove it.

Comment: @PaddyD For example: If you have a `space`, you will want to add code to `Replace Values` / `space` / with `null` (be sure to type out `null` in lower case, and also select, under Advanced, that it be the entire contents in case you have spaces in any of your `sku`'s.  You can do something similar for `no break space`.  IF neither of those work, we can add a column with code to figure out the ascii code of the blank character(s).

Comment: @PaddyD By the way, I can tell there is something in those cells because, unlike the column `Column1` in your screenshot, those cells are blank rather than displaying *`null`*. The cells have to be *`null`* in order for `fill down` to work.

Comment: Your right, they were blank, but not blank, got that sorted now, but now i'm stuck with "Extract a List of the elements of the _image_media column"  ( I skipped "extract the _media_attribute_id" don't need it), I can see where to do this as "extract values" is greyed out, and Text column > extract does not have "list" in it. https://snipboard.io/5dSHXA.jpg

Comment: sorry did not see your other 2 comments, I just filtered the blank cells and then deleted them, as you said they then showed as "null"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115090/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-paddyd).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new column to represent SKUs per line. The first row should have the SKU value. The next row should have `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),A2,D1)` where A2 is replaced with whichever column holds the sku data and d1 is the first row of that new column. Drag the formula down to the end of your data.
2. Create a second new column for the concatenated strings of the file names. Enter this: `=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,if(D:D=A1,C:C,"")),"")`. Here, D:D represents the column that you created in the step before, A1 is the original sku, and C:C is the column that has the media file names. Before you click out of it, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. (This creates it as an array function instead of a normal function). Drag this formula down to the end of your data.

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm guessing that I'm doing something stupid here, but when I try your solution i get this: https://snipboard.io/yKW0IP.jpg     (My data starts on the 2nd row so I updated the values accordingly

Comment: Change your D2 to D1 in that. If the SKU column is blank, we want to reference the cell directly above (moot for the first row, but important for others)

Comment: ok that makes sense now you have pointed it out